# use node-gyp exception : LNK2001 unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, c, node.js, visual-studio-code, node-gyp

use node-gyp build native module（try to use ffmpeg to my cpp files), it throws an exception: error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol

example code:

```cpp
index.cpp

    #include <node.h>
    extern "C"
    {
      #include "demo.h"
    }

demo.h

    int testFn();

demo.c

    int testFn(){
        return 0;
    }


binding.gyp

    {
      "targets": [
        {
          "target_name": "addon",
          "sources": [
            "index.cpp"
          ],
         "include_dirs": [
            "<!@(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').include\")"

          ],

          "dependencies": [
            "<!(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').gyp\")"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

build error info

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (D:\node-v9.3.0-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:159:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "D:\\node-v9.3.0-win-x64\\node.exe" "D:\\node-v9.3.0-win-x64\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\createVideo
gyp ERR! node -v v9.3.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
```

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong in my invocation of the above?
Thank you.

ps:
I tried to edit binding.gyp file (add libraries item）

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "addon",
      "sources": [
        "hello.cpp"
      ],
     "libraries": [
         "D:/lib/ffmpeg-4.2.1-win64-dev/lib/**"
      ],

      "dependencies": [
        "<!(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').gyp\")"
      ]   
    }
  ],
}
```

node-gyp build is ok , but can't work , run .js file to require native module exception  Error: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: Probably want to include your MSBuild output

Comment: I don't see a LNK2001 in the build output, can you please clarify that? In any case, search for that error code (if it actually occurs) before asking questions to get a clue what it means. BTW: What if you don't mix C and C++?

Comment: output result : hello.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol testFn [D:\createVideo\build\addon.vcxproj]
D:\createVideo\build\Release\addon.node : fatal error LNK1120: 1unresolved-externals [D:\createVideo\build\addon.vcxproj]

Comment: if I don't mix C and C++ , it is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may not have included the library files

for example, u have a header file with some functions

but the functions never declared because  the CPP file or the library is not present

Comment: you mean that I need  compile  .h and .c file to a libray files before  included them ?

Comment: libraries must have given to you ;
when u get linker errors, it means the compilation was successful without any errors but linker couldn't found the declaration for functions, classes,etc.. in 
the libraries that it knows, you have to give the linker your library path, or .lib,.dll file